# How to implement Laravel Websockets (demo project by beyondco.de) with SSL using Apache on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, pusher

I tested the demo projects locally and is working fine but failed when using and applying SSL to it in my DigitalOcean droplet (Ubuntu 16.04).

I have been looking for a fix and tried several suggestions already but I still keep on getting failed WebSocket handshake error with response code of 404.

See the image below:

[image]

Hope someone could share their solutions on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I only need to add ***sudo*** to start the Websocket successfully.

> sudo php artisan websockets:serve

All the settings/configurations were followed religiously as described here:  https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/ssl.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

In the SSL section of your `config/websockets.php`, try setting **verify_peer** to **false**.

Also make sure you configure SSL properly https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/ssl.html#configuration